# JMETER 5.6.3 , Status of view Result tree is in colour warning: Java exception error

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing

I am using JMeter and while runing my first test, the status of view results table is in red colour warning. I also double checked networ, java path and install /reinstall jmeter from the official website. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the system under test doesn't respond in 20 seconds. We don't know the reason and cannot reproduce your issue because we don't see your [HTTP Request](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request) sampler configuration.

So far I can only suggest [enabling JMeter debug logging](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-logging) for [Apache Httpcomponents](https://hc.apache.org/) by adding the next line to *log4j2.xml* file:

```
<Logger name="org.apache.http" level="debug" />
```

and looking into [jmeter.log file](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) to see if you will be able to figure out the cause of the failure from there.

Also double check protocol, hostname, port, path and so on to make sure that you're sending the request to correct endpoint.

If might be a good idea to record your scenario using JMeter's [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html)